# Check if array value empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement

I'm trying to check if array `beda[i].person.name` value is **empty**. But it keeps ignoring it. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with **if** *statement*

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (beda) {
        console.log(beda);

        for(var i = 0; i < beda.length; i++){
           $("ul").first().append( "<li>" + beda[i].person.name + " ... " + beda[i].character.name + "</li>");
           console.log(beda[i].person.name)

        if ( beda[i].person.name == '' ||  beda[i].person.name == null ||  beda[i].person.name == undefined || beda[i].person.name.lenght == 0) {
            $("ul").first().append( "<li>" + "No names found!" + "</li>");
     }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `console.log (beda[i].person.name)` You will understand whats going on

Comment: I already had that in my code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you have a typo. `lenght` should be `length`.

Also note that you can use type coercion to simplify the `if` statement:

```
if (!beda[i].person.name) {
  $("ul").first().append("<li>" + "No names found!" + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: I have tried you solution, but its still not working.